# TypeScript Class as ViewModel using Knockout?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, typescript

I am currently creating my Knockout ViewModel like this,

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.MyObservable = ko.observable();

}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Is there a way to use this TypeScript Class as a ViewModel?

```
class MyViewModel {

}
```

I know in the end the TSC generates a function anyway but to stick with the TypeScript convention I would just like to know if it is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Since TypeScript would eventually be compiled to JavaScript, why not? If you're looking for Knockout API exposed via TypeScript, see https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/knockout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, in many of my projects I use TypeScript for my KO viewmodels.
The following TypeScript:

```
class MyViewModel {
    MyObservable = ko.observable();
    MyComputed = ko.computed(() => {
        return this.MyObservable() * 2;
    })
}
```

Renders the following valid viewmodel:

```
var MyViewModel = (function () {
    function MyViewModel() {
        var _this = this;
        this.MyObservable = ko.observable();
        this.MyComputed = ko.computed(function () {
            return _this.MyObservable() * 2;
        });
    }
    return MyViewModel;
})();
```

Be careful when using functions though; the following TypeScript function:

```
MyFunction() {
    if (this.MyComputed() > 4) {
        alert('Higher than 4');
    }
}
```

Will render:

```
MyViewModel.prototype.MyFunction = function () {
    if (this.MyComputed() > 4) {
        alert('Higher than 4');
    }
};
```

Meaning you might run into scope problems with `this` when you're using this function directly in your binding for example (`data-bind="click: MyFunction"` would fail).

To prevent these scope issues, you should be declaring the functions in your viewmodels as lambas:

```
MyFunction = () => {
    if (this.MyComputed() > 4) {
        alert('Higher than 4');
    }
}
```

Renders:

```
    this.MyFunction = function () {
        if (_this.MyComputed() > 4) {
            alert('Higher than 4');
        }
    };
```